# Having numerous Reflectors in a scene: How to implement a clone() function?

Tags: three.js

I need about 80 (moving) reflecting `ShapeBufferGeometry` in a scene and i want them to share as much material data as possible.
Apparently, the `clone()` method doesn't work with `Reflector`.
I get black geometries that don't reflect anything.
Tried to add a `clone()` method to the `prototype` as below, resulting in no visible result at all:

```js
// Clone function for Reflector
Reflector.prototype.clone = function() {
    return new Reflector( this.geometry, this.options );
}
```

How would this work? Can share a Reflector among many objects?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I need about 80 (moving) reflecting ShapeBufferGeometry in a scene and i want them to share as much material data as possible.

Please be aware that each instance of `Reflector` renders its environment with a separate render pass. I highly doubt that 80 reflectors in a scene are going to produce a usable performance.

Besides, `Reflector` is not designed for sharing materials. A `clone()` method can't be implement without refactoring the implementation of `Reflector`. The purpose of a `clone()` method is questionable anyway since you can only have a small amount of mirrors in your scene. And all of them have to maintain unique uniform data. The renderer will automatically ensure to share shader programs across materials with compatible material settings. So there should no noticeable performance hit even if many objects have unique material objects.

Comment: Thanks, @Mugen87.
Actually it seems not impossible to render on my old Samsung Galaxy S5 and on my HP Omen w/ NVIDIA 970GTM.
Of course, i need to implement a switch on/off for the Reflector and a technique to refresh the view only when needed - at least at a framerate around 2-5fps which is fine for heliostat use cases :)
Have a look at http://oktoskop.com/Aurora/sim/ in the meanwhile and at http://oktoskop.com/Aurora/pres/ for understanding the goal.